# Calculation of direction vector

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

If i turn a line whose initial direction vector components were (0,1) in left in 2D space in 15 degree angle what would be the direction vector and its component?
I tried to do it using the law,

```
   x=0*cos(15)+1*sin(15);
   y=0*sin(15)-1*cos(15);
```

but i'm getting wrong answer.Can you please provide the calculation briefly?

Comment: Double-check your “law.” There are at least two errors in it.

Comment: what are those problems? i couldn't figure out :(

Comment: You’ve got two $\sin$ factors in the expression for $y$. The expression for $x$ is suspect, too, since rotating $(0,1)$ to the left by anything up to 180° has to end up with a negative $x$-coordinate.